# Change Gmail Contact defaults

Tags: gmail, contacts

When I enter information in a Gmail Contact, it defaults the phone number to Mobile.

How do I get it to default to Home?

Answer (score 3):

I dont think this is possible. I think it will always default to mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Short of writing a Greasemonkey script there's no way to customize this option.  Sometimes for trivial options the complexity of adding an option is not worth the extra convenience.